# Interpolating between two arbitrarily oriented ellipsoids

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, rotation, interpolation

I'm not sure if this would be better asked on Mathoverflow, but I thought I would check here first. I have tried to be as clear and concise as possible; if there is anything that needs clearing up please let me know.

**Background**

I have two sets of points in R3 that are distributed in the form of (more-or-less) arbitrarily oriented ellipsoids. I wish to interpolate a tubular structure between these two ellipsoids. I also have coordinates of the desired centre line of this tubular structure.

I approximate the ellipsoids at either end with a minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid using the Khachiyan Algorithm implemented in Matlab, [1] which returns the coordinates of the centre of the ellipsoid (C), and matrix of the ellipse in centre form (A), such that:

```
(x - C)' * A * (x - C) = 1
```

I then extract the ellipsoid's axes lengths (a,b,c) and the rotation matrix (V) using singular value decomposition:

```
[U,D,V] = svd(A);
a = 1/sqrt(D(1,1));
b = 1/sqrt(D(2,2));
c = 1/sqrt(D(3,3));
```

I can easily interpolate the axes length parameters (e.g. linear, spline). To interpolate between the orientations, I first convert the rotation matrices to quaternion representation. Then for each point along the centre line, I use spherical linear interpolation (SLERP) implemented in another Matlab file [2]:

```
for iPoint = 1 : nPoints
  t = iPoint / (nPoints + 2);
  quat = slerp(startQuat,endQuat,t,0.001);
  R = quat2rot(quat);
end
```

**This is where I get stuck.**

Unfortunately, even though SLERP "gives a straightest and shortest path between its quaternion endpoints," [3] the resulting interpolated ellipsoids are *sometimes* rotating in the "wrong" direction. That is, rather than resulting in a smooth tube, the interpolation results in a sort of twisted elliptical cylinder (see attached image, below).

I have tried checking to see if the dot product of the two quaternions is negative and if so, inverting one of them using `quatinv`. However, inverting results in something completely incorrect (see second attached image, below).

My question is: why is this happening, and what can I do to correct for this behavior? That is, how can I interpolate along the "true" shortest path between the two ellipsoid orientations?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I have created a minimum working example and a required data file. I have also attached a screenshot of the result. I've zipped these up and uploaded them to Dropbox. [4]

[image: Ellipsoid Interpolation]

[image: Ellipsoid Interpolation with inversion]

[1] http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542-minimum-volume-enclosing-ellipsoid/content/MinVolEllipse.m

[2] http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11827-slerp/content/slerp.m

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

[4] https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38218/ellipsoidInterpolation.zip

Comment: Ellipsoid or ellipse? Is the goal to obtain a protrusion along one axis that has a cross section generated from two ellipses? Or is a shape with elliptical ends and the interpolation occurs between them.

Comment: Ellipsoid; this is in R3. However, the axis length along the direction of interpolation isn't particularly important, since I want to end up with a tubular structure.

I'm not sure what you mean by a "protrusion along one axis..." but it sounds more like the latter: a shape with elliptical/ellipsoidal ends, with the interpolation occurring between them.

Comment: Your "tubular structure" is R3, but cross-sections along the center line are ellipses (or some form of [great circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatCircle.html), i.e., contours on the surface of an ellipsoid), no?

Comment: You should provide some form of very simple demo (with links to code or sub-functions if necessary) if you hope for others to see what is going on and be able to help. My only thought is that it might come down to how your ellipsoids (or ellipses) are discretized and how elements in each correspond with one another, but I'm guessing a lot as to what you're doing.

Comment: I've created a minimum working example (code and data file), and uploaded them to Dropbox. I've also updated the original post with the link and a screenshot.

Comment: Okay, from what I see, you don't have any "tube" or "cylinder". You have one ellipsoid in a given configuration that you're trying to interpolate the motion of along a center line to a final configuration. Why are you using `isosurface` and not the `ellipsoid` to display your data? You seem to have all of the necessary parameters to use the latter. As is the visualization is nearly impossible to interpret because of the lumpiness.

Comment: And the code you provided runs, but is far from minimum. It may do what you want, but unless you can point to specific parts of it that are problematic, it's too much for anyone to wrap their head around. Have you run your algorithm with much simpler geometries? Say, one vector interpolated along a center line to another configuration. Or a much a triangle, etc.? Does that work?

Comment: I don't have any tube or cylinder, but that's what I would like to end up with. `ellipsoid` is for mesh surfaces, but I'm working with binary volume data. I've added a call to `smooth3` to smoothen the rendering. I've updated the code on Dropbox as well, and attached an updated screenshot. I *believe* the problem is somewhere in lines 37-55 (or in the functions called in those lines).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to rotate everything by the inverse of the rotation matrix of one of the reference ellipsoids, such that that reference ellipsoid was axis-aligned (i.e. had no rotation). Then after interpolating each ellipsoid, rotate it back to the original reference frame by multiplying by the original rotation matrix.

I've attached a screenshot of the result:

[image]

**Update**

Apparently this does not work in every case. I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827518/slerp-direction-takes-the-long-way-around).

Comment: And of course the [inverse of a rotation matrix is just the transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Multiplication).